# How to Use VCPKG to Build Cairo as a Static Library?

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, cairo, vcpkg

I've been trying to install Cairo using vcpkg on the latest build of Windows 10, using the following to compile:

```
`.\vcpkg install cairo:x64-windows-static`
```

But run into an error when vcpkg attempts to build glib as a static library:

```
`Error: Building package glib:x64-windows-static failed with: BUILD_FAILED`
```

It's unable to install glib as glib only supports dynamic builds, though I am building Cairo statically.

How might I remedy this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: A port request on the vcpkg git hub is probably the only course of action you have unless this is due to a bug in the existing ports. I somewhat doubt that, but you never know. After the boost 1.70 upsize I'm no longer able to build cpprestsdk on a vs2015u3 environment. The core builds somehow id the environment as vc6 (yeah, not making that up, it would be hysterical if it wasn't so sad). That broke everything downstream. Anyway, if a port and  architecture you seek isn't available, you can request it, and/or contrib it. Worth looking in to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I've submitted the request.